# Change each number within a DIV into its own variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, blob

Here is my current code

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qbEGyB

Here specifically is the JavaScript portion

```
function readBlob(opt_startByte, opt_stopByte) {

var files = document.getElementById('files').files;
if (!files.length) {
    alert('Please select a file!');
    return;
}

var file = files[0];
var start = parseInt(opt_startByte) || 0;
var stop = parseInt(opt_stopByte) || file.size - 1;
var reader = new FileReader();

// If we use onloadend, we need to check the readyState.
reader.onloadend = function(evt) {
    if (evt.target.readyState == FileReader.DONE) { // DONE == 2
        document.getElementById('byte_content').textContent = evt.target.result;
    }
};

var blob = file.slice(start, stop + 1);
reader.readAsBinaryString(blob);
}

document.querySelector('.readBytesButtons').addEventListener('click', function(evt) {
    if (evt.target.tagName.toLowerCase() == 'button') {
        var startByte = evt.target.getAttribute('datastart');
        var endByte = evt.target.getAttribute('dataend');
        readBlob(startByte, endByte);
    }
}, false
);
```

It also requires a regular old .txt file which contains the following - http://textuploader.com/5ucnk

This all works lovely, you upload the .txt file, click the "code" button and it gives you ten two-digit numbers.

However, I have no way of addressing the individual two-digit numbers within the DIV. Is there a way to segment the content of the DIV so that I can manipulate each set of numbers as its own variable?

For instance, say I want to create a button that when pressed, increases the first number of the sequence by 1. And the number is determined by what is in the text file. I imagine "parseInt" would come into play here, but I really just want to see if there's a way I can either control the input of the BLOB function (so that it maybe disperses each set of double digits into a separate span?) or just find a way to address each specific two-digit-number within the DIV as a variable.

Someone suggested in a previous post that I use

```
var obj = {X:void 0, Y:void 0};
var res = document.querySelector("div").textContent.match(/\d+/g);
Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(val, i) {
  obj[val] = res[i]
});
```

However, appending this to my JavaScript, despite changing the "div" name, broke my code.

I'm really having trouble with this, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean to do something like this?

Basically, the div's contents are parsed out into an array of numbers called `z` that can be accessed like any other array.

```js
var z=document.querySelector('div').innerText
              .split(/\n/g)
              .filter(function(x){
                return !isNaN(x)&&x.replace(/\s/g,'')!=''; //remove non-integers
              });

//test to see that this works
document.querySelector('span').innerHTML='<pre>variable "z" is set to: '+JSON.stringify(z);
```

```html
<div><pre>This is a save file for LevelUp. 
07
10
20
31
41
59
26
53
54
97</pre><div>
<span></span>
```

Comment: Works JUST as I imagined it would. Thank you so much, I have been struggling with this for WEEKS!